# Super simple map LWC isn't working

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I'm trying to follow an example for a super simple map LWC that plots some coordinates and I'm just getting nothing.

Can someone point out my obviously stupid error? I can't get the markers to render on the map. The class returns the right data, but I'm not seeing the pins.

Thanks in advance.

Apex Class:

```
public class GetHeadstoneLocation {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Location> GetHeadstoneLocation() {
        List<Headstone__c> heads = [SELECT Id, Headstone_Location__Latitude__s, Headstone_Location__Longitude__s FROM Headstone__c ];

        List<Location> loc = new List<Location>();
        for(Headstone__c head : heads) {
            system.debug(head);
           Location locDetail = new Location();
           locDetail.icon = 'action:map';
           locDetail.title = head.Name;
           locDetail.description = head.Name;
           locDetail.latitude = head.Headstone_Location__Latitude__s;
           locDetail.longitude = head.Headstone_Location__Longitude__s;

           loc.add(locDetail);
        }
        return loc;
    }

    public class Location {
        @AuraEnabled
        public String icon{get;set;}
        @AuraEnabled 
        public String title{get;set;} 
        @AuraEnabled
        public String description{get;set;} 
        @AuraEnabled 
        public Double latitude{get;set;} 
        @AuraEnabled 
        public Double longitude{get;set;} 
        }
        }
```

Controller:

````
import GetHeadstoneLocation from '@salesforce/apex/GetHeadstoneLocation.GetHeadstoneLocation';

export default class CemetaryMap extends LightningElement {
    @track headstones = [];
    @track error;
    @track showFooter = true;

    @wire(GetHeadstoneLocation)
    wiredHeadstones({error,data}) {
        if(data) {
            this.headstones = data;
            console.log(data);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data,null, '\t'));
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
        }
    }
}```
````

HTML:

```
    <h6> Cemetary Maps Example </h6>
    <template if:true={headstones}>
        <lightning-map map-markers={headstones}  markers-title={headstones}>
        </lightning-map>
</template>
</template>
```

I must just be doing something wrong somewhere. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: try changing 'latitude' to 'Latitude' and same for longitude in apex class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you JS file try adding Latitude and Longitude like this:

````
import GetHeadstoneLocation from '@salesforce/apex/GetHeadstoneLocation.GetHeadstoneLocation';

export default class CemetaryMap extends LightningElement {
    @track headstones = [];
    @track error;
    @track showFooter = true;

    @wire(GetHeadstoneLocation)
    wiredHeadstones({error,data}) {
        if(data) {
        this.headstones = data.map(stone => {
        const Latitude = stone.latitude;
        const Longitude = stone.longitude;
        return {
            location: { Latitude, Longitude }
        };
    });  
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: If I map them this way, how can I get the titles to show up instead of just the coordinates?

Comment: Its the same way how you get location. Have a variable this.title and assign the value from the incoming data

Comment: I got it, thanks <3